# Can't return address from JsonRpcSigner from wagmi to pass into parameter view function

Tags: ethers.js, json-rpc, react, wagmi

Trying to pass the connected wallet address into one of my view functions, but cannot get the address from the JSON object is there something I am missing here? Using wagmi to get signer from the connected wallet and I see the correct wallet showing in JsonRpcSigner JSON format in the browser console. I cannot pass signer, or signer[_address], or signer.address, or signer[0,1] through to viewProfileStrings(signer) function:

```
import { useContractRead, useContract, useSigner } from "wagmi";
const { data: signer, isError, isLoading } = useSigner();
console.log("here is the ", signer);

(async () => {
    const function_return = await myContract.methods
   .viewProfileStrings(signer)
      .call();
    console.log("info 1 attempt", function_return[0]);
    setInfo(function_return[0]);
    return function_return;
  })();
```

[image: correct wallet address console.log from the browser]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it!

```
  const [finalAddress, setAddress] = useState("");

  const { data: signer, isError, isLoading } = useSigner();

  (async () => {
    const finaladdressusestate = await signer.getAddress();
    setAddress(finaladdressusestate);
  })();
```